# Change color of UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uicolor

Hello,

I created `UINavigationBar`, and I try to change the color bar to aqua color (As in Nib file)

How do I do it?

Answer (score 8):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:.62 blue:.984 alpha:1]];
```

Dude, try this to get `[UIColor Aqua]` throughout your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can set either `tintColor` or `backgroundImage` to your `UINavigationBar`

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   //set background image
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

  //OR set background Color
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

I'm not sure but if you'll put this in first call method of your app it may apply everywhere!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { }
```

Comment: I try with the code [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; and code [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0] but the blue is darker than aqua. And I can not reach to aqua color

Comment: @user1669223, You should find the color code for `AQUA` (RGB). Use mac in-built `DigitalColor Meter` and hover the cursor from which you want RGB and set the color code. You've to set RGB like, `e.g. 125.0/255.0`

Comment: The RGB for Aqua color is 255 blue 128 green 0 red but is light blue not aqua

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
```

Please try above code for set color.

**Edited**

```
 UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
UIColor* aqua = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
[bar setTintColor:aqua];
```

This Code use for the aqua color

Comment: I can not reach to aqua color this that's the problem

Comment: *@user1669223 "I can not reach to aqua color this that's the problem"* This is not a designers q&a. If your only problem is that you can't create aqua color using RGB, you should go to Photoshop and experiment. You shouldn't ask here how to create it

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
UIColor* aqua = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor aqua];
```

regards

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Call this function befor the ViewController will appear, e.g. in `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: please make sure that you answer is to the question, otherwise you will get down vote, for your attention, im not the one who voted down here

Comment: My answer isn't wrong. If you read the question, it's not clear if the problem is, how to set the navigationbar color or just how to get the color aqua.